# How to add a custom domain bought in goDaddy in parse.com

Tags: hosting, parse-platform

I created an app/project in parse.com. I am using parse hosting service. I created a parse app name which ends with "someName.parseapp.com".

I bought a domain in GoDaddy that I now want to point to my parse app, I know that I need to add a CNAME record on GoDaddy but not sure what it should be (www is already there...). Can anyone tell the exact steps to be done?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have just successfully completed the process doing the following.

PART A: Forwarding *www.yourapp.com* to *yourapp.parseapp.com*

1. Go to GoDaddy Domain Details
2. Click on DNS Zone Files
3. Under CNAME set *www* to point to your *yourapp.parseapp.com*
4. In Parse, go to go to your application -> Settings -> Hosting
5. In Host Name put *www.yourapp.com*

PART B: Forwarding *yourapp.com* to *yourapp.parseapp.com*

1. In GoDaddy create A host record for *yourapp.com* to link to 54.85.233.145 and 54.85.226.190 (create two A records) [1]

And that's it :)

[1] https://parse.com/docs/hosting_guide#custom

Comment: still really struggling with this :(

Comment: so with the CNAME, it originally was 'www' -> so now im going to change it to mywesitename.com and im going to change the points to part to myparseapp.parseapp.com? is this the correct procedure?

Comment: EVERYBODY!!! make sure that you put the WWW in the Host Name on the parse dashboard!!

Comment: Ok, I've made the changes, but it sometimes it work, sometimes it don't, do you know why ? (Safari works, Chrome don't)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with a Heroku app, pretty sure this is the same process.
Try this short tuto :

http://thenomadicfreelancer.blogspot.fr/2012/08/pointing-godaddy-domain-to-your-heroku.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on [Jirka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27162942/131385) which is the correct answer.

I just wanted to add that this only seems to work for the hostname 'www'. I've tried it with others like 'clients' but it didn't work (just a completely blank page served by Parse (no error).

So, if you want to have a naked domain served on Parse hosting you can do it but in my tests you have to have the app Hostname set to **www**.yourdomain.com in their 'Custom Domains' settings.